# Desktop mode Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: 17.04, desktop-environments, unity8

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 17.04. When I use Unity 8, it works fine. However, when I use the default desktop mode, I get a

> Ubuntu 17.04 has encountered an internal error

dialogue box repeatedly. Is something wrong in Ubuntu 17.04?
Kindly assist me.

Comment: The error messages are probably a result of something that happened with regards to unity8. There is probably nothing wrong with the normal session. Also unity8 is no longer supported, and 17.10 has been released, so you really should upgrade to 17.10 at this point, as 17.04 will be end of life in January 2018.

Comment: Unity8 is working fine. The normal session is the one giving the error messages.

Comment: No, the error messages only pop up in the normal session. See what files are in `/var/crash` to see what the crash reports are for.

Comment: How do I see what is in  /var/crash ?

Comment: Open the directory with the file manager, or run `ls /var/crash` in a terminal.

Comment: _usr_bin_gedit.1000.crash  _usr_bin_mediascanner-service-2.0.1000.crash  _usr_bin_terminal.1000.crash  _usr_bin_terminal.1000.upload  _usr_bin_terminal.1000.uploaded  _usr_lib_x86_64-linux-gnu_policykit-unity8_policykit-agent.1000.crash